# jQuery replaceWith function flash

Tags: jquery

I use the jquery.replaceWith() function.. it work fine but when i used it on image, it create a flash. What i mean is it replace the image-a by image-b but while image-a is deleted, and image-b is loaded, there is NOTHING, so the box is 0px height and that make all the layut change for 1 second and flash everything...

What should i used, or how to make replaceWith() put the image only after it have been loaded, so replacing it will be instantaneous.

you can get a look at the nextgen gallery image browser sideshow problem here
http://mecanomedic.com/cms/

Comment: are you just changing the `src` of the image?

Comment: Do you always change one image with one image in replace with ?

Comment: I change A LOT of thing, prev button ref, next button ref, lightbox clik ref, etc etc...

Comment: Are the dimensions of the new images the same as the old images?

Comment: ALL IMAGES are exactly the same (little is : 267x200) and click on show the big one... 800x600...have not figure out yet how to show thumbnal in the little version it's just the 800x600 scaled, but it's more like a preload if click and lightbox open !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the dimensions of your images are always the same, you can specify the sizes on the `<img>` tag:

```
<img class="slideshow" src="/path/to/my/image001.jpg" width="267" height="200">
```

Or with CSS:

```
.slideshow {
    height: 267px;
    width: 267px;
}
```

This should prevent the element from changing sizes while the new image loads.

Also, you may want to simply change the `src` of the `<img>` tag, rather than replacing the entire DOM entry:

```
$(currentimage).attr('src','/path/to/my/image002.jpg');
```